# How do I link an image in my plugin so it displays on WordPress?

Tags: plugins, images, plugins-url, linking

I'm creating a plugin for a college project. The plugin is very simple: it searches for name of the site address and upon finding it in a post, it outputs the site address with an image. However, I cannot get the code working. I've tried this:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Murtaghs Trademark Plugin
Plugin URI: http://www.MurtaghsPub&Undertakers.ie
Description: Adds Murtaghs Logo Wherever name Of Business Displayed On Page.
Author: Connell Gray
Version: 1.0
Author URI: http://www.MurtaghsPub&Undertakers.ie
*/
function Murtaghs_Trademark_Plugin($text) {

    $site_name = get_bloginfo();
    //the logo.jpg file is stored in a folder called images which i  have created in the plugins folder//
    $new_site_name = $site_name . '<sup>echo '<img src="' . plugins_url( 'images/wordpress.png' ,"logo.jpg"  ) . '" > '</sup>';

    $text = str_replace($site_name,$new_site_name,$text);

    return $text;
}
add_filter('the_content','Murtaghs_Trademark_Plugin');

?>
```

Comment: Check the documentation for [`plugins_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url) -- your 2nd parameter is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

This line is your problem:

```
$new_site_name = $site_name . '<sup>echo '<img src="' . plugins_url( 'images/wordpress.png' ,"logo.jpg"  ) . '" > '</sup>';
```

Here you've muddled up the quotes and put PHP code inside a string expecting it to still work.

e.g.

```
echo ' this is inside a quote:' inside a quote ' . ';
```

It doesn't work because the quote in your string closes the starting quote, ending the string. To fix this you need to either:

- use a double quote
- escape your characters

e.g.

```
echo 'this is inside a quote \' inside a quote \' .';
```

As a side note, make sure that your code editor supports syntax highlighting with a good colour scheme, it will make these kinds of issues more obvious.